# confused about how populate listview

Tags: c#, listview

I have a table with 2 columns: `username` and `age`. What I want to do is to populate a ListView with data coming from the database. I think I missed out something because every time the form is loaded the ListView is empty. I have noticed that the `DataReader`'s property `HasRows` return *false* while debugging.

```
  void populate()
    {  
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from users ", con);
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(dr[0].ToString());
            lvi.SubItems.Add(dr[1].ToString());
            listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
        }

        dr.Close();
        dr.Dispose();
    }

   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (con = new SqlConnection("server=.\\sqlepxress;database=Projects;Integrated Security=sspi")) {

                try
                {
                      con.Open();
                     populate();

                }
                catch (SqlException x )
                {

                    MessageBox.Show(x.Message);
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: From your description it seems that `dr` is actually returning no rows. Are you actually connecting to the database you believe you are connecting to?

Comment: I agree with Codor, please confirm you are returning rows and then we can go from there

Comment: Make sure you close your connection or use a `using` statement. Breakpoint over the retrieving-datapart, and see if `dr` gets filled.

Comment: do you get any exception in Message box??

Comment: Please see updated code.Now I get exception while connection db.a network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to sql server

Comment: The scope of the connection may be coming into play here. I typically keep my connection and my sqlcommand all in the same function, or if I can't, pass the connection between the functions if I set it up early.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your Connection string isn't valid, try:

```
con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=....;Initial Catalog=..;Connect Timeout=15;Integrated Security=sspi";
```

OR (in case Windows Authendication has problems :)

```
 new SqlConnection("Data Source="+...+";Initial Catalog=Projects;User id="+user+";Password="+pass+";Connect Timeout=15;Integrated Security=false");
```

Comment: hi @apomene .My connection string is true but thanks your advice .I have modified my connection string like this way. "Server=.\\sqlexpress;Database=Projects;User Id=sa;Password=1234" and ıt works great.But why???any idea

Comment: please be careful not to  publishing credentials..maybe WIndows Authendication had an issue...Check with Management Studio if you can connect with windows Authendication..

Comment: Yes I can connect both way via Management Studio.Thank you friend.